# How can I do infinite loop in for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, infinite-loop

i want to loop with a list and each list infinite loop meets a certain conditions.
But I just get first element result. how can I fix code?

```
final_complex=pd.DataFrame()
n=1

for code in ['111552', '101410', '103177']:
    while True:
    

        url='''https://new.land.naver.com/api/articles/complex/111552?realEstateType=
                APT%3AABYG%3AJGC&tradeType=A1&tag=%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A&rentPriceMin=0&
                rentPriceMax=900000000&priceMin=0&priceMax=900000000&areaMin=0&areaMax=900000000&oldBuildYears&
                recentlyBuildYears&minHouseHoldCount&maxHouseHoldCount&
                showArticle=false&sameAddressGroup=true&minMaintenanceCost&maxMaintenanceCost&
                priceType=RETAIL&directions=&page={}&complexNo=3756&buildingNos=&areaNos=&type=list&order=rank'''.format(n)

        headers={
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
            'authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IlJFQUxFU1RBVEUiLCJpYXQiOjE2NjMwNzMwNDQsImV4cCI6MTY2MzA4Mzg0NH0.ZJ8FLYxYpdkrsrXneI5OBjUNPxSzCbMsymxGEAg1ZX0',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Host': 'new.land.naver.com',
            'Referer': 'https://new.land.naver.com/complexes?ms=37.3595704,127.105399,16&a=APT:ABYG:JGC&b=A1&e=RETAIL',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.9 Safari/537.36',
            }

        res=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        res.json()
        data_dict=res.json()
        temp=pd.DataFrame(data_dict['articleList'])
        if len(temp)==0:
            break
        final_complex=pd.concat([final_complex,temp])
        n+=1
final_complex
```

Comment: Where are the 3 lists? I only see 1 list.

Comment: i don't see `code` being used anywhere either, so i don't think the output will change between different outer iterations either ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.